# Issue while casting jsonb to bigint in deeplink

Tags: sql, postgresql, deeplink

While casting in same DB working fine, But failing while with deeplink

Working fine in the same DB (Getting result with this query):

```
SELECT id, 
       total_inventory, 
       hotel_id, 
       ( room_type -> 'id' ) :: bigint AS room_type_id, 
       created_by, 
       created_date, 
       modified_by, 
       modified_date 
FROM   hotel_inventory;
```

Not working while connecting with other DB (using deeplink) (Error with this query):

```
INSERT INTO hotel_inventory 
            ( 
                        id, 
                        total_inventory, 
                        hotel_id, 
                        room_type_id, 
                        created_by, 
                        created_date, 
                        modified_by, 
                        modified_date 
            ) 
SELECT * 
FROM   dblink('demopostgres', 'SELECT id, total_inventory, hotel_id, (room_type -> 'id')::bigint as room_type_id,  created_by, created_date, modified_by, modified_date FROM hotel_inventory') 
AS data(id bigint, total_inventory integer, hotel_id bigint, room_type_id bigint, created_by jsonb, created_date timestamp without time zone, modified_by jsonb, modified_date timestamp without time zone);
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id"
LINE 3: ...ECT id, total_inventory, hotel_id, (room_type -> 'id')::bigi...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 221
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double up the single quotes to avoid such an error:

```
dblink('demopostgres',
       'SELECT . . . (room_type -> ''id'')::bigint as room_type_id . . . '
      )
```

The issue is a simple parsing error.  The single quote ends the string -- hence the error.  The double single quote is the standard way of putting a single quote in a string, although different databases often support other methods (such as a backslash).